# MVC 6 WebAPI returns serialized HttpResponseMessage instead of file stream

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make my ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 WebAPI project output a file, in response to a HttpGET request.

The file is from an Azure Files share, but it could be any stream containing a binary file.

It seems to me that MVC serializes the response object, and returns the resulting JSON, rather than returning the response object itself.

Here is my controller method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetFile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string Username, string Password, string FullName)
    {

        var client = new AzureFilesClient.AzureFilesClient(Username, Password);
        Stream azureFileStream =  client.GetFileStream(FullName).Result;
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(FullName);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            response.Content = new StreamContent(azureFileStream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
            return response;
        }
    }
```

The GetFileStream method on the AzureFilesClient is here, though the stream source could be anything containing binary file content:

```
    public async Task<Stream> GetFileStream(string fileName)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(share.Uri + "/" + fileName);
        var file = new CloudFile(uri, credentials);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Here is a sample of the JSON response:

```
{
    "Version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Build": -1,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "Content": {
        "Headers": [
            {
                "Key": "Content-Type",
                "Value": [
                    "application/octet-stream"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Key": "Content-Disposition",
                "Value": [
                    "attachmentx; filename=\"samplefile.docx\""
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
    "Headers": [],
    "RequestMessage": null,
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Comment: Had a similar thing happen to me. I posted the answer in this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391748/1858296 . But I see your question was more involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a combination of reading documentation aswell as some trial and error, the problems have been solved.

The Azure part was made using the nuGet package "WindowsAzure.Storage" (4.4.1-preview)

First the output that got JSON serialized.
That required a custom action result to be returned instead.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class FileResultFromStream : ActionResult
{
    public FileResultFromStream(string fileDownloadName, Stream fileStream, string contentType)
    {
        FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;
        FileStream = fileStream;
        ContentType = contentType;
    }

    public string ContentType { get; private set; }
    public string FileDownloadName { get; private set; }
    public Stream FileStream { get; private set; }

    public async override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = ContentType;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", new[] { "attachment; filename=" + FileDownloadName });
        await FileStream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
    }
}
```

Now for getting the binary data streamed from an Azure files share (or any other async stream source)

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public async Task<Stream> GetFileStreamAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(share.Uri + "/" + fileName);
        var file = new CloudFile(uri, credentials);

        // Note: Do not wrap the stream variable in a Using, since it will close the stream too soon.
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return stream;
    }
```

And finally the controller code. Note the use of the IActionResult interface.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string username, string password, string fullName)
    {
        var client = new AzureFilesClient.AzureFilesClient(username, password);
        Stream stream = await client.GetFileStreamAsync(fullName);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
        return new CustomActionResults.FileResultFromStream(fileName, stream, "application/msword");
    }
```

Note: This example is only used with Word files, you might want to look into making the ContentType parameter dynamic, instead of static like this.

Comment: Good answer, and still works. The AspNet team implemented their own FileStreamResult : FileResult : ActionResult solution, but did not make it available in the System.Net.Http namespace that ApiController uses. So here is the source if you'd like to use it:  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FileResult.cs

Comment: This is solution works nicely for me, but I'm still confused about what ultimately closes the stream. Does it just get disposed on garbage collection? Or should it get closed at the end of the ExecuteResultAsync method?

Comment: How have you found performance with large files (~500mb) ? I am running into issues on slower connections dropping out after ~200mb. Faster connections have no issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have only used this for ~1-15mb files, mainly Word and PDF documents. Performance was excellent in this situation.