# .NET REST API HttpResponseMessage is serialized to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, rest

I am attempting to write a simple REST API in C# that connects to a database. Right now, I am working on `POST` for one of my objects, and I am attempting to return a `HttpResponseMessage` based on the result of that operation. For some reason, when I attempt to return an `HttpResponseMessage`, however, it is serialized into `JSON`!

Here is my code for the `POST` method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand comm = connection.CreateCommand();

        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT_T(product_name, price) "
            + "VALUES(@product_name, @price)";

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", product.ProductName);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", product.Price);

        try
        {
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("bad request");
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        connection.Close();
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

I am using the Chrome extension Postman to test my API. When I send bad data intentionally, you can see in the screen shot below that the status code of the response is `200`, and my `HttpResponseMessage` with code `400` is serialized as `JSON` in the body of the response.

Can someone tell me how to actually set the status code of the response itself?

[image: capture from Postman]

Comment: Maybe this had something to do with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391748/1858296

Answer (score 0):

Get in the habbit of of having all your APIs return `Task<IHttpActionResult>`

**Example:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/alerts/helloWorld")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> HelloWorld(string someInput) {

    return Ok("hello world");

    //or, if the request was bad
    return BadRequest("hey, you did something wrong!");

}
```

Comment: from which packages are you using HttpPost, IHttpActionResult, and Ok/BadRequest? I am having issues resolving conflicts between System.Web.Http and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: those are all built in to the .NET API 2.   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [tutoriel](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) it help me for my first web api. Like jhilden said IHttpActionResult work better for handling response and the reson the response is in json format is probably cause you havent specified the Accept header in your html post if you add Accept: text/xml you will see your result in xml