# Web API 2 : Returning binary file with "application/octet-stream" not working with IIS Server : IIS/10.0 but working with IIS/8.5

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have web api which returns binary file, which is consumed by Angular 12 client. Application is deployed on Dev and Integ environments. Now suprisingly, same api is working on Dev but not on Integ. When on Integ, instead of returning binary file, it returns **JSON**. The only difference is Dev IIS Server (hosting API) version is 8.5  while that of Integ is 10.0.

I have also added necessary response header like :

```
 result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

Below is the sample response returned on Integ :

```
{
  "Version": {
    "_Major": 1,
    "_Minor": 1,
    "_Build": -1,
    "_Revision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/octet-stream"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Below is my API code :

```
   [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Chart/test")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> test(TestEntity request)
        {
            try
            {
                var ms = await _service.testMethod(request.Data, request.ExportType, request.FileName);
                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray())
                };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                return result;
            }
        }
```

And below is my angular method code :

```
 angularTestMethod(request) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}api/Chart/test`, request, { withCredentials: true, responseType: 'blob'})
    .pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
  }
```

Any idea what could be the issue? As code of angular and web api is same for both environments.

Below are the version details :

```
Angular : Angular 12,
Web API : ASP.Net Web API 2.2
.Net Framework : 4.6.1

Dev Windows Server and IIS : 2012 and 8.5 resp
Integ Windows Server and IIS : 2016 and 10.0 resp
```

Comment: Have you got any error messages when running Web API 2 in iis10?

Comment: Nope.. no error message. Just receiving response in JSON instead of getting binary file.

Comment: It is difficult to solve your problem without error message, I suggest you open a case via : https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had some conflicts in the System.Net.Http assembly earlier and I had installed Nuget Package for System.Net.Http but I did not check in Binding redirects.

This answer "[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391748/3883342)" to another SO question helped me with it. I uninstalled the Nuget Package and Installed it back and then checked in all Binding Redirects generated in Web.Config and it fixed the issue.